# Salesforce Lightning Design System in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce-lightning

I would like to use the Salesforce [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) (SLDS) in a Ruby on Rails application, but I cannot figure out how to get any of the styles to render. Has anyone had experience using SLDS in a rails applicaiton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used SLDS, but adapting the basic [tutorial](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/heroku/) I got a basic (static) page with styles going in a few minutes using Sprockets. There's various options documented for installing the framework, so this is just the way I picked as opposed to the only way:

1. Download the pre-built CSS framework from the [installation page](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/downloads/).
2. Unzip and copy/move the `/assets` directory into your app under `vendor/assets`.
3. Edit `config/initializers/assets.rb` to load assets from the vendor directory (if you don't already):

```rb
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor/assets')
```

4. Add the Salesforce CSS to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```rb
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require salesforce-lightning-design-system
```

As I said, this is just a simple way via the Sprockets asset pipeline. If you are installing the framework via yarn and packaging CSS with Webpacker instead of Sprockets, you'll need to import the style into a stylesheet pack and include it with a `stylesheet_pack_tag`, etc.